# Need help integrating Flask webhook receiver and API data fetching in my Tkinter app

Tags: python, api, flask, tkinter, webhooks

I have a Tkinter app that fetches data from an API and shows it on the Tkinter app in a tree view widget.
The API also receives the data and gives a response.
What I want to achieve is to include a webhook URL widget in my app which will enable the user to input a source webhook URL and whenever there is a signal from the webhook source I want to process that data and send it to the API to get the response.
I can't figure out how to do this, webhook receiver flask runs all the time in the background which stops the other API data fetching processes

I tried to add my Flask webhook receiver app (which works fine individually ) and it stops all the other processes. I am fetching data from api every 3 seconds for updates but the flask app runs all the time in the background which stops the data fetching.